# what is the relevence of -m 1

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am executing below sqoop command::=

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.xxx.xxx.xx:1435;database=RRAM_Temp' --username DRRM_DATALOADER --password ****** --table T_VND --hive-import --hive-table amitesh_db.amit_hive_test --as-textfile --target-dir amitesh_test_hive -m 1
```

I have two queries::-

1) what is the relevence of -m 1? as far as I know Its the number of mapper that I am assigning to the sqoop job. If that is true, then, the moment I assign -m 2, the execution start throwing error as below:

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: No primary key could be found for table xxx. Please specify one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'
```

Now, I am forced to change my concept, now I see, it has something to do with database primary key. Can somebody help me a logic behind this?

2) I have ordered the above sqoop command to save the file as text file format.But when I go to the location suggested by the execution, I find tbl_name.jar. Why, if --as-textfile is a wrong sytax, then what is the right one. Or is there any other location that I can find the file in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** To have `-m` or `--num-mappers` to be set to a value greater than `1`, the table must either have `PRIMARY KEY` or the `sqoop` command must be provided with a `--split-by` column. [Controlling Parallelism](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) would explain the logic behind this.

**2)** The FileFormat of the data imported into the Hive table `amit_hive_test` would be plain text(`--as-textfile`). As this is `--hive-import`, the data will be first imported into the `--target-dir` and then is loaded (`LOAD DATA INPATH`)  into the Hive table. The resultant data will be inside the table's `LOCATION` and not in `--target-dir`.